Does something really exists?
There exist multiple ways to describe that something exists. It depends on what we want to exist :

A physical object that exists because it's composed of matter or energy. The main argument is that "it's just there". Example : "This apple exists."
An immaterial object like an idea or a concept. It's often built on a human abstraction of our world : "sadness" is not made of matter or energy, but we "know" it exists. Example : "Sadness exists."

This leads to several questions:

Do matter and energy really exist or is it just an abstraction due to our point of view ? (yes, atoms and energy are mathematical "simplifications" of our world)
Do immaterial concepts like "sadness", "morality" and "justice" really exist or are they just abstractions and thus do not exist ?
And if [matter and energy] exist and [concepts] do not, does the word "exist" mean two different things ? If yes, is our language flawed or is there a deeper contradiction ?


If you realize that the word "exists" is ambiguous and can mean whatever suits people's purposes  then what is the point of asking your questions? "This" does not lead to them, it leads to them being pointless.

Per dialetheism there’s conventional existence and ultimate existence which is ontologically prior to and thus precedes all conventionally existing essences, assuming it exists…

The dialetheism is due to Dasein being grounded by ultimate existence (indefinable and indeterminate) in contrast to conventional existence which is Dasein's determination of entities. So conventional existence depends on ultimate existence. That is to say beings are grounded by Being, which in turn is groundless, and in fact eludes determination altogether, most interestingly. It's not really a dialetheism though because the extantness of beings is not on the same level as Being, so they don't contradict each other as dialetheism suggests.

Well, the English language is not suitable for such things. Let's find out what a language such Greek has to say : The word exists is the word υπάρχει, from the words υπό and αρχή. υπό means under...
As for αρχή, we get from the dictionary.
https://el.wiktionary.org/wiki/αρχή

A point in space or time when something begins.
The primary cause.
The origin; the beggining of the creation of something.
Α fundamental rule / principle in nature, science, art, politics.
A basic rule that governs personal or social behaviour.

So, we only need to understand the meaning of the word to discover all the philosophical insights that you are talking about. Have fun!
Ah, and something else, the word is female, which means that it denotes a process of (continuously) "becoming of ..." vs acting upon.
So, ... to an answer, yes, everything that you say exists, because everything is under a 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc.

Apparently, for υπάρχει one meaning is "there is", vis. WordHippo, on which page further down is mentioned 'is': είναι. And we can see how this is understood from Parmenides: τὸ γὰρ αὐτὸ νοεῖν ἐστίν τε καὶ εἶναι "For thinking and being are the same." Note 3, 'usual' translation.

@Chris Degnen, Considering νοεῖν as thinking and υπάρχει as "there is", is a simplification, similar to telling a child that he was born when his father kissed his mother. Unfortunately all translations are wrong and especially the older ones, upon which others are based and on and on.

Still the Parmenides fragment doesn't seem to contradict modern existentialism insofar as objective existence depends on the objective determinations made by an observer, and subjective existence has a mode of 'thinking', or more basically, understanding. The usual problem is the 'existence' of unobserved things. We know there are unobserved things and that's where the matter can rest. Observed, determined things can be understood to have been existent prior to determination, but in the prior time they were undetermined.  υπάρχει, perhaps can mean 'under determination'.

Re. "wrong translations". I found this in Gayatri Spivak's preface to Derrida's Of Grammatology, (page xxi) quoting Derrida: "The history of metaphysics, like the history of the West, is the history of these metaphors and metonymies.(18) Its matrix — if you will pardon me for demonstrating so little and for being so elliptical in order to bring me more quickly to my principal theme — is the determination of being as presence in all the senses of this word. It would be possible to show that all the names related to fundamentals, to principles, or to the center have always designated ...

the constant of a presence — eidos, archè, telos, energeia, ousia (essence, existence, substance, subject) aletheia, transcendentality, consciousness, or conscience, God, man, and so forth." (L'écriture et la différence 410-11, The Structuralist Controversy 249) / Note 18. Here Derrida's often implicit Freudianism surfaces. The history of metaphysics, like a dream-neurosis-psychosis, is constituted by distortion. Metaphor and metonymy are rhetorical translations of "condensation" and "displacement," two major techniques, as Freud pointed out, of dream-distortion (see also page xlvi).

@Chris Degnen, keep in mind - during your quest - that "modern" Greek suffer from the same problem (and distrortion of meanings) as English. So, translations have to be made in the context of the initial authors. Indeed if you ask a living Greek person what υπάρχει means, he would probably say exists, but ... I and you and all of us here, what this "exists" means, is what we are searching for...
